# nestjs-i18n in DTO validation just throw bad request error

Tags: internationalization, nestjs, dto, class-validator, nestjs-i18n

im using nestjs-i18n in my dto and it just throw bad request error instead of my error messsage.

this is my dto:

```
export class SignUpDto{
    @ApiProperty()
    @MinLength(5, {
        message: i18nValidationMessage('i18n.MIN', {message: 'err'})
    })
    username:string;
}
```

and i18n.json file:

```
{
  "MIN": "You need to write at least 5 letter"   
}
```

but this is the error in swagger:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
}
```

what is the problem?

Comment: It got fixed. I forgot to define `@UseFilters(new I18nValidationExceptionFilter())` in controller.

Answer (score 1):

the best way:
1)you can use this code in your main.ts

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new I18nValidationPipe());
```

2)and in your classDto code is

```
  @IsNotEmpty({
message: i18nValidationMessage('fa.validation.IsNotEmpty', {
  field: 'createdAt',
}),
})
createdAt: string;
```

3)in your controller

```
  @UseFilters(new I18nValidationExceptionFilter())
  # or use in your main.ts this code
  app.useGlobalPipes(new I18nValidationPipe());
  app.useGlobalFilters(new I18nValidationExceptionFilter());
```

4)in your i18n folder file like:fa.json

```
  "validation": {
"IsNotEmpty": "fulllllll iiittt"
}
```

Comment: https://nestjs-i18n.com/guides/dto_validation/global-validation

Comment: where is I18nValidationPipe? it's not in nestjs-i18n. using version 9.0.10